# 404 custom page not working with useContext and React Router

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-hooks

If I type in a URL that doesn't exist in my app, it sends me to a custom 404 Not Found page.
However, when I wrap my Navbar with `<User.Provider value={value}> .... </User.Provider>`, the 404 Not Found component appears on all pages.

Basically, I don't want the `NoMatch` component to appear on all other pages, only when a url does not exist/match with my app's navbar.

So if I type in localhost:5000/this-does-not-exist-12345212wergdv
it should take me to the custom component, `NoMatch`.

Code sandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-sea-b2r96?file=/src/App.js

Anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks for any help.
My code below.

UserContext.jsx code

```
import React from "react";

export const User = React.createContext(null);
```

Home.jsx code

```
import React from "react";
import {User} from "../auth/UserContext";

const Home = props => {
    
    const {user} = React.useContext(User);
    
    return (
 
    <div>
        <h4>This is Home page</h4>
        <h4>User: {JSON.stringify({user})}</h4>
            </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

Navbar.jsx code

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  useLocation,
    useHistory
} from "react-router-dom";
import {User} from "../auth/UserContext";
import Home from "../pages/Home";

const Navbar = React.memo(props => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const value = React.useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser]);
    const history = useHistory();
    
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/old-match">Old Match, to be redirected</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-match">Will Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-not-match">Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/also/will/not/match">Also Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
        <User.Provider value = {value}>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/old-match">
            <Redirect to="/will-match" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/will-match">
            <WillMatch />
          </Route>
            
          <Route path="*">
            <NoMatch />
          </Route>
        </User.Provider>
            
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
})

function WillMatch() {
  return <h3>Matched!</h3>;
}

function NoMatch() {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

App.jsx page

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

export default function App(props) {
  return (
      
      <div>
          <Navbar/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a code sandbox?

Comment: Sure. https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-sea-b2r96?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that the `Switch` component looks *only* at its direct children for the `path` property regardless of whether or not they are `Route`s.

In this case, since the direct child of `Switch` is `User.Provider` with no `path` property the switch will always just render that child (a switch will always render at least one child).

Now the children of `User.Provider` will be rendered, and the `Switch` will no longer have any bearing. This means now that the `<Route path="*" />` will *ALWAYS* render like you are seeing.

**Solution:**

The solution is to just move the location of the `User.Provider` to surround the `Switch` component.

```
const Navbar = React.memo(props => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const value = React.useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser]);
    const history = useHistory();
    
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/old-match">Old Match, to be redirected</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-match">Will Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-not-match">Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/also/will/not/match">Also Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <User.Provider value = {value}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/old-match">
            <Redirect to="/will-match" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/will-match">
            <WillMatch />
          </Route>
            
          <Route path="*">
            <NoMatch />
          </Route>                
        </Switch>
        </User.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
})
```

Comment: Thanks, very grateful. I should have realized it was the `Switch`.